# The way to extract 10-band equalization information from mp3 format

Tags: audio

I want to make a 16 band graphic equalizer for my mp3 player.

However, I don't know where to start because I have no experience on audio processing.

So, I really have no idea where to begin to extract the frequency bands(?) from the mp3 format.

Would somebody please suggest me a easy solution to do this?

Ah, also, is there any open-source mp3 player which is easy to modify and to build as a windows application?

Comment: I don't understand why would you want to **extract** frequency bands in order to set an equalization?

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't need to set equaliztion... I just want to make some kind of graphical 16-band bars?? ... And I don't know how to extract those information....

Answer (score 9):

I think what you are looking for is a spectrum analyzer. It shows the instantaneous energy level at various frequency ranges across the audio spectrum. For most people, it is basically eye candy. It does not modify the signal.

A graphic equalizer, on the other hand, allows you to boost or attenuate the energy of the audio at various frequency bands. It definitely modifies the signal. Most people use graphic equalizers to boost parts of the spectrum for effect, like boosting the bass.

Audiophiles typically use a spectrum analyzer wired to a microphone (not an amplifier) to monitor the response of a room in which white noise is being played through a graphic equalizer. They then adjust the equalizer to flatten the frequency response, thereby compensating for the acoustics of the room to give you a more pure hearing of recorded audio. These people typically get very upset if you then mess with their equalizer settings. :)

You could look at popular Linux mp3 players like RhythmBox, Banshee, VLC, or even Audacity. If you want to write your own, here are some instructions. Assuming you know how to write a GUI program on Windows, and you just want a nice spectrum analyzer, what you really need to do is the following:

1. Tap in to the signal path after the decoding stage.
2. Downmix the audio to mono, which usually means just adding the left and right samples together. Be careful to either use floats for the audio (which should be scaled to +/- 1), or cast the (presumably 16-bit) samples to 32-bit integers before adding to avoid overflow when adding shorts.
3. Measure out some number of samples (called a window), typically 512, 1024, or 2048 (always choose a power of two). There is a tradeoff here between resolution (larger windows have higher resolution), cost (more samples take more time to process), and responsiveness (larger windows take more time to accumulate, lowering the frame rate of your analyzer).
4. Run these samples through a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT). Consult the documentation for the FFT library you use ([FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) is a good one), but the output is typically an array of complex numbers, symmetrical about the middle.
5. If the output is symmetrical, use just the first half. If it is not symmetrical, then use the whole thing. Each complex number from beginning to end (or middle) encodes the energy and phase of a sinusoid at a linearly spaced frequency from 0 Hz to half the sample rate of the audio. If the audio is 44.1 kHz, and you chose 1024 samples in your FFT, then each number represents 22050 Hz / 512 = 43 Hz.
6. Take each complex number and square its real and imaginary parts and add those numbers. You'll end up with the power (i.e. energy squared) in each bin, which is a real and positive number.
7. Group the FFT bins into frequency bands by adding them up. For example, if you took the 512 bins in the example above and grouped them by 51, you would have 10 bands of 2196 Hz. This provides too little resolution in the low frequencies, so people typically use logarithmically spaced bands: 0 (0-43 Hz), 1 (43-86 Hz), 2-3 (86-172 Hz), 4-7 (172-344 Hz), 8-15 (344-688 Hz), etc.
8. You can now either display the power sums directly, or compute an average for each band and then take the square root of that (the RMS energy) and plot that. To display values in decibels, compute the RMS energy, and then plot this: `20 * log10(RMS / 32768)`. Values go from 0 dB (full scale) to -90 dB (silent) for 16-bit audio.
9. Repeat steps 2-8 continually, updating your display each time.
10. Go impress your friends.

Good luck with this. And if you don't see much energy above 16 kHz, don't be alarmed. The mp3 encoding algorithm filters out everything above 16 kHz to help with the compression.

p.s. If you are really good, and have source for the decoder, then you can access the audio when it is still in the frequency domain in the decoder and use that for the spectrum analyzer. You'll have to take what the decoder gives you in terms of window size, but your computational costs will be almost zero. And beware that mp3s use the Discrete Cosine Transform, not the Fourier Transform, to move audio to and from the frequency domain, so your energy values will be different than with a proper FFT.

Comment: Yes, @iDroid. After conversion to the frequency domain, you would multiply the values in each bin by a scaling factor (>1 to boost, <1 to attenuate) whose value comes from the 10 bands of equalization you are trying to apply. In other words, map your 10 equalization band settings into the N frequency bins and multiply. Then perform an inverse FFT to bring the audio back to the time domain. You might need to overlap your FFTs by N/2 and apply a window function to the audio if equalization is introducing artifacts (i.e. there are discontinuities in the sound wave at the window boundaries.